# How to get user email address using pinterest authentication api?

Tags: pinterest

i am using pinterest api to register a user on my website. i get user id, first name, last name and url. but email is not given in the response. how can is there any api to get email of pinterest user?

Comment: Did you try doing a google search to find this information?

Comment: You can't get the email. We didn't want their contact information to just anybody. Sorry!

Comment: @Theresa yes i do a lot off google search but in fail

Comment: @ZackArgyle then how can we uniquely identify the user and what data we store in database instead of email

Comment: You can just use the user's <id> field which is absolutely unique to all Pinterest users.

Answer (score 2):

You cant get email address of Authenticated user via API. Pintrest do not provide that detail through API.